# powershell windows form button link

Tags: powershell, windows-forms-designer

How would i link a buttton to open a batch file in windows forms using powershell, i have the following code below just need the add click event

```
$run = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$run.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(95,450)
$run.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$run.Text = "Run"
$run.Add_Click({   })
$objForm.Controls.Add($run)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By open, do you mean execute the script or edit it in a word processor?

You can treat the brackets within the Add_Click event like any 'ole [ScriptBlock].

To execute the batch file:

```
$run.Add_Click({ Invoke-Expression "cmd /c c:\path\to\batch\file.bat" })
```

Or, open it in notepad:

```
$run.Add_Click({
    Write-Verbose "Running Batch Script!"
    Invoke-Expression "notepad c:\path\to\file.bat"        
})
```

Or call some other function..

```
$run.Add_Click({ Start-MyFunction })
```